# ARMv8 exception vector significance of EL0_SP

Tags: arm64

I am new to ARMv8 architecture and while reading the v8 exception vectors I am not able to understand significance of adding SP_EL0 level vectors while SP_ELx vector set exists. What I am trying to find a use case where this is useful. I understand that when the exception is taken at same level by default the stack of same exception level  is used for example if EL2 (Hyp) mode is defined then if exception occurs while being at EL2 level the stack defined at EL2 will be used but not sure if I configure to use EL0 level stack under what use cases this could be useful ? Can some one give a use case and explain ?

Also while going through the spec it seems these two different stack usage idea is taken from Cortex-M architecture but i am not very clear with thread and handler modes as well. Can any one explain it ?

Just wanted to add here that ARMv7 doesn't have thread and handler concept so i am not clear requirement in ARMv8.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SP_EL0 is the "normal" stack pointer.  Your code that runs in any EL should be running on SP_EL0 whenever it can.  SP_EL1/2/3 is the "exception" stack pointer for that mode.  When an exception, fault, or interrupt happens, the processor switches to this stack (and possibly switches EL).  Your exception handler code should do what it needs to save the exception state and get itself onto SP_EL0 to complete handling the exception.

That is, your EL0 user code, your EL1 kernel code, your EL2 hypervisor, and your EL3 monitor should all be using SP_EL0 except in the early stages of their exception handlers.  If you were to take a nested exception while on SP_ELx (non-zero), you could blow over your stack, ELR, FAR, etc. which is why you want to save these and get back to SP_EL0 as soon as you can.

Comment: In case of ARMv7 there is banked SP for IRQ so does above mentioned problem with stack overflow can still occur for nested interrupts ?

Comment: arm64 does not have separate interrupt stacks, SP_EL1 is used as the stack for handling what used to be done in SVC, Abort, IRQ, and FIQ modes in ARMv7 (32-bit).  Interrupts are masked when an exception occurs.  Do not enable interrupts until you are ready to handle them.  This is when your code is back on SP_EL0 and sufficient state has been saved.

Comment: @VariableLengthCoder I am also wondering about the SP_EL0 being used in other EL. What i understand ( i could be wrong) is EL0 code will be running in its virtual address space and EL1 where any exception  from EL0 is handled is run in its own different address address space. So you say `If you were to take a nested exception while on SP_ELx (non-zero), you could blow over your stack, ELR, FAR, etc` I am confused here as I wonder whether switching to SP_EL0 will switch the address space we are working with (i think this is not the case). Why would ELx run out of stack space?

Comment: Typically you would load the address of your an EL1 stack into SP_EL0 before switching to it from SP_EL1.  The code would not be using the same stack as EL0 (which is probably in its own VA space, as you said), instead it would switch to the kernel's interrupt stack or kernel thread stack or other dedicated stack for handling the trap (placing it in SP_EL0).